# Prevent manual subscription from triggering on initial load

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a model that I am populating with data from the server.  The problem is, when that data is initially populated my subscription is firing which I don't want.  I only want the subscription to fire when the user interacts with the UI.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    //Populate the object.
    self.request = new Request(data);
    //Subscribe to one of the "properties" so that I can do stuff when the value changes.
    self.request.selectedId.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        //This is firing before the user interacts with the UI.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you don't need manual subscriptions for that, but if you want to keep them because you need to do something just once, you can always use a flag that triggers once.

```
self.initialLoad = true;
self.request.selectedId.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if(self.initialLoad) self.initialLoad = false
    else {
    //This is firing before the user interacts with the UI.
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using the manual subscription to kick off an Ajax call.  Would you suggest a different way?

Comment: In terms of performance having an `if` is harmless. I would be worried if it's too easy for the user to perform an AJAX call through a UI component. To what HTML element is this observable binded to?